# Builder pattern that forces all members to be initialized at compile-time

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

[This java answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/212835/189787) made me wonder whether it would be possible to implement the builder pattern in C++ in a way that checks at compile-time whether all necessary members of the constructed object are actually set before the object is constructed. [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7069f8709a75805) is what I came up with:

```
struct Foo {
    int x_;
    int y_;
    int z_;
};

template <bool x_set = 0, bool y_set = 0, bool z_set = 0>
struct FooBuilder {
    int x_, y_, z_;

    Foo build() {
        static_assert(x_set && y_set && z_set, "all members must be initialized before building a Foo!");
        return { x_, y_, z_};
    }

    FooBuilder<1,y_set,z_set> x(int val) {
        FooBuilder<1,y_set,z_set> result;
        result.x_ = val;
        result.y_ = y_;
        result.z_ = z_;
        return result;
    }

    FooBuilder<x_set,1,z_set> y(int val) {
        FooBuilder<x_set,1,z_set> result;
        result.x_ = val;
        result.y_ = y_;
        result.z_ = z_;
        return result;
    }

    FooBuilder<x_set,y_set,1> z(int val) {
        FooBuilder<x_set,y_set,1> result;
        // optional check to allow z to be set only once
        static_assert(!z_set, "z may not be initialized twice!"); 
        result.x_ = val;
        result.y_ = y_;
        result.z_ = z_;
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    FooBuilder<> b;
    auto f1 = b.x(1).y(2).z(3).build();
    auto f1a = b.z(3).y(2).x(1).build();
    auto f2 = b.x(1).y(2).build(); // fails with static assertion 
    auto f3 = b.x(1).y(2).z(3).z(4).build(); // fails with static assertion 
    auto partially_initialized_builder = b.x(1);
    auto f4 = partially_initialized_builder.build(); // fails...
    auto f5 = partially_initialized_builder.y(4).z(6).build(); // runs

    return 0;
}
```

With this approach, I like the fact that programming errors that result from forgotten arguments to the builder can be caught at compile-time. However, I'm not sure if it is too verbose, since the whole content of the builder has to be copied/moved in each setter method (even if the copies might be optimized away).

So my main questions are:

1. Would such a pattern actually be useful in practice?
2. Is there an elegant way of sharing the member variables of the `Builder` objects, despite the results of each setter call being of a different type? (For cheap-to-move types, I am thinking along the lines of a "data block"-like struct, that gets `move`d from `this` into the `result`.)
3. Any other downsides to this approach?

P.S.: Please disregard the lack of access control (`x_` etc. should be private), this question is more about the high-level picture ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would such a pattern actually be useful in practice?

Not really in my opinion. In C++20 you can use designated initializer lists like `{.min = 10, .max = 20}` and I mean if the argument is not clear from the context than there are various ways to improve this, even today.

1. A comment. `Foo f(/*min=*/10);`
2. User-defined literals `Rectangle r(10_width, 200_height);`
3. Strong types: `Player p(Position(10, 10));`
4. Variables: `const int size = 10; Square s(size);`

This also doesn't work with non-copyable, non-moveable types, although those are rare in practice. The members also need to be default constructible unfortunately.

Some thoughts:

1. Note that your code has undefined behavior, since two of the variables are not set on the first call.
2. The `build` function is required in Java, but in C++ you can use a conversion operator. Although this suffers from the same problem that expression templates have: Using type deduction will not get you a `Foo`.
3. Delete copy construction for the builder object, since there is no reason to copy it.
4. Don't use `0` and `1` for bools please; `false` and `true` is clearer IMO.
5. Consider using `noexcept` and `constexpr` (if applicable).

> Is there an elegant way of sharing the member variables of the Builder objects, despite the results of each setter call being of a different type? (For cheap-to-move types, I am thinking along the lines of a "data block"-like struct, that gets moved from this into the result.)

Yes that's a good idea. Here's my take on it:

```
template <bool x_set = false, bool y_set = false, bool z_set = false>
struct FooBuilder {
  constexpr FooBuilder() noexcept = default;
  FooBuilder(const FooBuilder &) = delete;
  FooBuilder &operator=(const FooBuilder &) = delete;

  constexpr auto x(int val) noexcept {
    members_.x_ = val;
    return FooBuilder<true, y_set, z_set>(std::move(*this));
  }
  constexpr auto y(int val) noexcept {
    members_.y_ = val;
    return FooBuilder<x_set, true, z_set>(std::move(*this));
  }
  constexpr auto z(int val) noexcept {
    static_assert(!z_set, "cannot set z twice!");
    members_.z_ = val;
    return FooBuilder<x_set, y_set, true>(std::move(*this));
  }

  constexpr operator Foo() noexcept {
    static_assert(x_set && y_set && z_set, "all members must be set");
    return {members_.x_, members_.y_, members_.z_};
  }
  constexpr Foo build() noexcept { return *this; }

private:
  template <bool... args>
  constexpr FooBuilder(FooBuilder<args...> &&other) noexcept
      : members_{std::move(other.members_.x_), std::move(other.members_.y_),
                 std::move(other.members_.z_)} {}

  template <bool, bool, bool> friend struct FooBuilder;

  struct Proxy {
    int x_, y_, z_;
  } members_{};
};
```

There is still a lot of boilerplate, but unfortunately it cannot be removed since C++ doesn't have reflection yet.

Comment: It's also possible to write a macro to generate such a builder automagically :)

Comment: Thanks for your insights - especially the one about the C++20 designated initializer lists. They are almost exactly the feature that I wanted to emulate. Also, the variadic move constructor really reduces the amount of boilerplate code, great idea! (And the points about the copy constructor, 0/1, uninitialized variables are valid, I'll excuse that with me being a bit sloppy while writing the code ;) )

Comment: @Rakete1111, have you thought about tuple of `std::optional`s? I thought about using string literals as template arguments to create struct with named variables, but then recalled that I cannot name a member of a struct with compile time string. It would be great if one could overload operator-> to return one of those optionals properly named, and at the build phase check if all have been initialized. It will of course place constraints of being moveable and destructible, but I don't think it is too much to ask.

Comment: @Incomputable We need reflection like yesterday :)